# Keep getting invalid_auth for users.info for NEW slack apps (even copied from manifest!)

Tags: slack-api

Did something change recently on slack end for new apps? If I create a NEW slack app based off an existing manifest (or from scratch), I can proceed with oauth successfully, however a subsequent api request to users.info returns `error: 'invalid_auth'`. I know my scopes and setup are legit since this new app is a literal carbon copy of an existing app (which works beautifully)...so anybody know what is going?!?!?!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the token associated to the new app to make the API call? Might be worth double checking that you're not using the token from the app that was previously created.The wrong token will likely return and invalid_auth error.